# How to create a transparent plane?

Tags: texturing

As shown in the picture,
I have a plane, and would like to set it transparent,
while remaining the shadow for the cube.
I want to do this for video motion tracking.
How can I do this?

Thanks!!

[image]

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10650/manually-make-it-look-like-an-object-is-going-through-the-floor-of-a-real-life

Comment: Here's a tutorial on making a "shadow catcher" http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k7gKzgvFiGM