# Make transparent object get shadow from particles in Blender

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, transparency

I created a mesh, then use particles to make grass on it. I just want to take the grass and grass's shadow on render, so I make the mesh's material become invisible (by using Transparent BSDF, alpha is zero).

But when the mesh become transparent, the grass's shadow is disappear too. How can I still get the shadow while the mesh is invisible?

I use Blender 2.70, Cycles Render

[image: The grass's shadow is disappear when the mesh become transparent]

Comment: Thank you for fast replay. I tried it, but there is no "Set Alpha" node in my "Add > Converter" menu. May be in 2.7 version it has been deleted or renamed or something?

Comment: @user2695076 Make sure you are using composite nodes

Comment: What you are looking for is called a "shadow catcher". A transparent plane that receives the shadows of generated objects but is otherwise transparent. Read this http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10650/manually-make-it-look-like-an-object-is-going-through-the-floor-of-a-real-life and watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k7gKzgvFiGM&feature=youtube_gdata_player

Comment: Wait, I just noticed that the example image is transparent. Do you want the shadows to be rendered over image alpha? Or do you want objects behind the plane to be visible?

Comment: @gandalf3 I want the shadows to be rendered over image alpha.

Comment: @cegaton Thank you! That link is exactly what I need! I tried and successful.

Comment: @user2695076 :) Please feel free to write an answer to your own question so others can learn from it.